# Django trying to add up values in the django template

Tags: django, python-2.7

Hi Guys I am trying to figure this out but not having any luck.

So I am showing my events in the homepage which shows how many seats are available, once the user has made a booking I would like to minus that from the amount showing on the homepage.

But I am already stuck at adding all the values up for that event in the booking model to minus from that amount.

So this is what I have

model for events

```
class Events(models.Model):

    ACTIVE = (('d', "Deactivated"), ('e', "Expired"), ('a', "Active"), ('b', "Drafts"),)
    ALCOHOL = (('0','No bring own alcohol'),('1','There will be complimentary wine pairing'))

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    price = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, default='')
    seats = models.IntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

model for bookings

```
class Bookings(models.Model):

    OPTIONS_STATUS = (('y', "Yes"), ('n', "No"), ('p', "Pending"),)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Events, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    eventdate = models.DateField()
    event_amount = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    guests = models.IntegerField()
    bookingstatus = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='p', blank=True, choices=OPTIONS_STATUS)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

my homepage how I get my data into a loop form the view

```
today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
events_list_data = Events.objects.filter(active='a').filter(Q(date__gte=today)|Q(date=today)).order_by('date')
```

How I am trying to show this in my template

```
{% for event_list in events_list_data %}
SHOW WHAT EVER DATA I AM SHOWING NOT NEEDED FOR HELP ON
   {% for bookingguests in 
   event_list.bookings_set.all %}
   {{ bookingguests.guests }}
   {% endfor %}
   Seats Left
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, purpose of templates is not to implement logic. All the logic should go into your views. I would recommend you to do that in your views and either store it in a dict or a list and send it to front-end.

Once the user made a booking, if you want to modify the value on the HTML without reloading, you may need to use jQuery/javascript. Otherwise, if you are fine with reloading the page by rendering it again with calculations from the backend.

By using jQuery:

```
$("#balance-id").html(logic to get the balance)
```

By Calculating in views:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
user_balance = user.balance - events_data.aggregate(Sum('price'))
return render('path/to/template', {'events_list': events_list_object, 'user_balance':user_balance})
```

In the template:

```
{{user_balance}} seats left
```

Let me know in case of any questions.

Note: If you want to write some logic into your templates, use [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/). It can help you with whatever it can with its limited functionality.

Comment: After calculating the difference value, you need send it to the template in the same return statement. Can you share your return statement, Where you are rendering the template.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028493/getting-the-amount-of-guests-in-bookings-made-django

Try this, Made another post that might give you a better view